# Populate nested ICollection within viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

Im trying to figure out a nice way to populate a nested collection model. I have the following in my viewmodel.

```
public class ListViewModel
{
    public ICollection<Wish> Wishes { get; set; }
}
```

The Wish model looks like this:

```
public class Wish
{      
    public ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
}
```

Now in my controller I want to populate the **ListViewModel** with wishes also populate each wish with their corresponding images. What I have so far:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ICollection wishes = _repoWish.GetAllAsync().Result;
    ICollection images = _repoImage.GetAllAsync().Result;

    var model = new ListViewModel
    {
       Wishes = wishes
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

I know I can make a lot of foreach statements but I want to make use of LINQ to populate each wish with their corresponding images.

**I do have a generic repository class which makes it possible for me to retrieve all images in the same manner as the wishes.

*** Think about the repositories as contexts.
So instead of _repoWish and _repoImage its wishContext and imageContext

I am using **ASP.NET Core 2.0** with **Entity Framework Core**

Comment: what does `_repoWish.GetAllAsync().` return ? and how are `Image` entity and `Wish` entity are connected in that result set ?

Comment: so your wishes are not coming with the images from your database?

Comment: You'd need loops or `linq` if you're [using a view model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc). What is wrong with the current code you have?

Comment: @Shyju It returns an ICollection of wishes. But the wishes are not populated with their images

Comment: @adiga Nothing is wrong with the code. I just need an extra step to populate each wish with their images.

Comment: Ok, so where do you get your images from? You should add code for that also.

Comment: You may need to include your navigational property `Images` like `.Include("Images")` if you are fetching your data from EF LINQ

Comment: @GauravSinghJantwal Yes that was what I was hoping you could help me with

Comment: Additionally `_repoWish.GetAllAsync().Result;` might create a deadlock, instead use `_repoWish.GetAllAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();` or use async/await

Comment: @GauravSinghJantwal the async/await is included within the GetAllAsync()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To load the related entities, you need to explicitly use the `Include` method call when you query the `Wishes` collection to eager load the `Images` property.

Also make sure you `await` your `async` calls.

```
var wishesWithImages = await yourDbContext.Wishes
                                          .Include(g => g.Images)
                                          .ToListAsync();
```

The variable `wishesWithImages` will be a collection of `Wish` objects with Images property loaded. You can now use that to populate your view model.

```
var vm = new ListViewModel { Wishes = wishesWithImages  };
```

Assuming your `Wish` entity has a collection property of type `Images`

```
public class Wish
{
   public int Id { set;get;}
   public ICollection<Image> Images { set;get;} 
}
public class Image
{
   public int Id { set;get;}
   public int WishId { set;get;}
   public virtual Image Image{ set;get;} 
}
```

As of today, Entity framework core is a light weight version of EF6  and doesn't automatically inherit all the features from EF 6. Lazy loading is not implemented yet in EF core.

Comment: So when querying 'wishesWithImages' the wishes are populated with the images? And yes the Image has a WishId

Comment: Yes. wishesWithImages is a collection of Wishes with Images property populated.